How to backup & restore filesystem metadata/attributes only?
Im currently trying to create a "shallow" backup of my whole filesystem, meaning that I should be able to somehow backup the current full filesystem structure, including mainly file ownerships and permissions, without the actual files contents for a fast "snapshot" of the filesystem in case I mess up the permissions at some later point, so I would be able to restore the ownerships and permissions recursively in such case.
The main objectives are:

The backup is very small in size since its only containing metadata (preferrably only ownership and permissions attributes)
The backup is fast(er) to create compared to an actual backup
The backup should be able to be restored 1:1 to the original target (ignoring new files missing from the backup)

Would this be possible e.g. using rsync, tar or similar tools?
A similar question was asked here.
However, Im looking for a full/comprehensive solution to the problem and objectives described.

I can do a new install from external SSD to internal SSD in about 10 minutes. Restore /home with rsync, install apps from backed up exported list and a few settings that I have not figured out how to script, yet. Or about an hour to a full restore. How much quicker do you expect to have?

It depends a lot on how much data you have. In my case, backing up and restoring close to a terabyte of data, I do not have enough space to have a backup for the whole filesystem. Just for the sake of messing up with attributes e.g. by misinterpreted chown/chmod helps a lot if I have e.g. daily backup of the metadata only.

I can try to answer the question myself. This answer probably requires corrections.
To backup the a directory, attributes only recursively and preservatively, and using tar to store the resulting structure in a single file, one can use:
[sudo] cp -rT --attributes-only --preserve=mode,ownership /path/to/source /path/to/dest
[sudo] tar -C / -cf /path/to/backup.tar /path/to/dest

And to restore, use reverse approach:
[sudo] tar -C / -xf /path/to/backup.tar
[sudo] cp -rT --attributes-only --preserve=mode,ownership /path/to/dest /path/to/source

Root/sudo required to preserve
